# How to update swing UI while ActionListener is in progress

Tags: java, swing

In my code below I want the TextArea to be cleared while the application is loading data. I also added a repaint() but still it's not  cleared. 
Do I have to notify it differently to force a repaint?

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            textArea.setText("");
            textArea.repaint();


            String result = //call a REST API
            textArea.setText(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't have to call repaint() explicity, what you want to do is call the rest api in another thread

Comment: `ActionListener`'s `acitionPerformed` method executes on the EDT. EDT is the thread that deals with UI updates (redraws). Calling `repaint` from the EDT will schedule a repaint as soon as pending events are dealt with. And while you are holding the EDT busy with your REST call, the repaint is not going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the time-consuming operation in another thread. You can use `SwingWorker`, which will notify AWT thread as soon as the computation completes.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    textArea.setText("");

    SwingWorker<String, Object> worker = new SwingWorker<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {                
            return ...; // call a REST API
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                textArea.setText(get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    };      
    worker.execute();
}
```

You can also use `invokeLater`, which will execute the REST call as a part of the event queue.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    textArea.setText("");

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String result = // call a REST API
            textArea.setText(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Except that `textArea.setText(result)` should be called from the EDT. `SwingWorker` is better suited in this case.

Comment: Actually, `invokeLater()` is also OK here. It also [executes code in EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid calling REST on the EDT? I mean, that was the primary issue with the author's code.

Answer (score 5):

What I think you want to do is calling the rest api in another Thread. You can do it with a `SwingWorker` that is designed to run heavily task in another thread without blocking the gui. Here is a complete example i really like [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT
       // call REST API here

      return null;
    }

   @Override
   protected void done() {
        //this is executed in the EDT
        //here you update your textArea with the result
   }
}
```

After the `doInBackground` method is finished the `done` method is executed. Then `SwingWorker` notifies any PropertyChangeListeners about the state property change to `StateValue.DONE`. So you can override this method here or use a propertyChangeListener implementation to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You run your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` method in EDT because of that you can't update UI. For updating UI from your code try to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), it can update UI while background process running.

Or you can try to use [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for background process and updating UI from EDT.